# fchmod function in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, chmod

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
void main()
{
    int fd=open("b.txt",O_RDONLY);
    fchmod(fd,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ls -l b.txt
----r----- 1 mohanraj mohanraj 0 Sep 12 15:09 b.txt
$ ./a.out
$ ls -l b.txt
----r----- 1 mohanraj mohanraj 0 Sep 12 15:09 b.txt  
$
```

For the above program, My expected output is to set the permission for b.txt as "rw_rw_r__". But, It still remains in the old
permission. Why it will be like this. Is this code have any bug ?

Comment: Ahem... `void main()`...

Comment: Check what [`fchmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchmod.html) returns, and if it fails then check `errno`.

Comment: I tested the program, and all function calls return zero.

Comment: Actually, on my system, this works perfectly fine.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank You. I found the answer. For file b.txt I didn't set the read permission for owner. So, While we calling the open function, it does not have permission to open b.txt. So, it returns bad file descriptor error. So, it will be like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file b.txt I didn't set the read permission for owner. So, While we calling the open function, it does not have permission to open b.txt. So, it returns bad file descriptor error. So, it will be like this.

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
void main()
{
      int fd=open("b.txt",O_RDONLY);
      perror("open");
      fchmod(fd,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH);
      perror("fchmod");
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
open: Permission denied
fchmod: Bad file descriptor
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission to modify the file, call your program with `sudo` to have it succeed.

Also always check the return value of functions like `open` and `fchmod` and handle the errors .

Comment: Can the downvoter care to explain why he thinks this answer is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should check if `fd` returned by `open` syscall is fine and you should check `fchmod` syscall status as well.

Secondly, I tested your example code and in my case it works as follows.

**Before running your program:**

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -l hej.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 0 Sep 12 11:53 hej.txt
```

**After running your program:**

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -l hej.txt 
-rwxrwxrw- 1 pi pi 0 Sep 12 11:53 hej.txt
```

**Your program might missing permission to this file.**

Answer (score 0):

$ ls -l b.txt
----r----- 1 mohanraj mohanraj 0 Sep 12 15:09 b.txt

**----r-----**, it means owner of b.txt has no Permission to read or write

```
$chmod 644 b.txt //add read and write Permission, -rw-r--r--
```

also, change file permission need **O_RDWR** flag

make sure function success before continue

```
void main()
{
    int fd=open("b.txt",O_RDWR);
    if (fd > 0) {
       //do some thing
    }
}
```